# JQuery on IIS 7 - crossDomain error using load

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, load, cross-domain

I'm using IIS 7 and want to host a static site on it. It's basically just HTML and a little bit JavaScript to load some content.

JQuery is loading fine. When I try to load one of my .tpl files in the subfolder there's the following error in my console (Chrome):

```
GET http://myLocalURL/new/assets/templates/home.tpl 404 (Not Found)
x.ajaxTransport.x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send
x.extend.ajax
x.fn.load(index)
x.Callbacks.l
x.Callbacks.c.fireWith
x.extend.ready
```

The file is there and the permissions are fine. It worked fine in my local test environment.

I try to load the .tpl files using the follwing code:

```
function show_content(id) {
    $('content_handler').load('assets/templates/'+id); };
```

As I said, everything worked fine in my local test environment.

However - all the bootstrap java stuff (e.g. popover) works fine.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you hit your  [http://myLocalURL/new/assets/templates/home.tpl](http://myLocalURL/new/assets/templates/home.tpl) in your browser, what do you get back?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. For whatever reason IIS does not like .tpl files...
Renaming the files to .html fixed the problem.

Cheers!